# Higher order function type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a `Provider` class that stores a handler function and can be executed with some context:

```js
interface ProviderHandler<A extends any[] = any[], R = any> {
  (this: RequestContext, ...args: A): R
}

type FlatPromise<T> = Promise<T extends Promise<infer E> ? E : T>

interface WrapCall {
  <T extends ProviderHandler>(provider: Provider<T>): T extends ProviderHandler<
    infer A,
    infer R
  >
    ? (...args: A) => FlatPromise<R>
    : never
}

interface RequestContext {
  /* ... */
  call: WrapCall
}

class Provider<T extends ProviderHandler = ProviderHandler> {
  handler: T

  constructor(options: { handler: T }) {
    this.handler = options.handler
  }
}

const context = { /* imagine it implemented */ } as RequestContext
```

Everything works great if handler is a simple function:

```js
const p1 = new Provider({
    async handler() {
        return 5
    }
})

// r1 = number
const r1 = await context.call(p1)()
```

But it does not work with generic handlers:

```js
const p2 = new Provider({
    async handler<T>(t: T) {
        return t
    }
})

// actual: r2 = unknown
// expected: r2 = string
const r2 = await context.call(p2)('text')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=50&ssc=42&pln=41&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYDdgBNoAScIuANtADwCCyEAHpCQM7LECeA2gLrIC8rITlwA0yAEp8BbAHzIA3gChkyABRgAFsCYAucRACOAVwhMwAYQzh6YUQDp7cKAHMdyKgEpdYhQF8FCsDYABxQAMVI4MHQMAFstCAoAFVl+aLimBMTaBghmNEx0hNAYaGQAUVkAfnLkXWT-UEhYRBQAdSg4ILM4UlJ5JWQk7MZcFmicfCgiEnIoaRUgzAnoXXG8SmTPZCzrXNH87HWp4jJKAeVi0qphc+RLqHEB6VvqlXtbRxddDz5ZcMi0vEKGJnsplLoQBAsNBfA0rM0kHojCZzJZIAx+soAPQAKmQ72QOKxAwQPVIunanW6vVhCgQESYYyWRyGuzya0m01OD1SzM5J1mskUynUApW238ygQllMUEMCDAGCgKgwQTAwBlujkyFFM3FWR87kxYI0Wlsuu5klV6pl5rFUAGfj8dJlYGQ0qsGP42txdxicCcoBQwDdwBiQXIMVykFwhKxyB8rBYYgMxlMFk9YH8HtMyCCAEZJJCAO4HZbK4VguBMNggBA6+0qI2VsFgqAQMCGKAgZAAVluTvc-ix8aghf4IEMMQARjCR8hi0qANYsGBBl0gXNjyRwYtwEPutHWWyk3oLfPuJvZ115gBMRYgpY50BULaTtfrFtmSXmYDqzduVt207btkCzVtB2HeNEE7HpdCge9+EMEAlxADBixABR53oEIFQgXB4MQ5BZVAJwsPjXAMBMEAAHI3UXKAlw3LciN3fc3Q9dEwBPMkFlvS86OsGihwUHClTdORE19f0lxMZA13IVhkBiDBcEMRSYCVMDVWQchoT6AADNiQwMuMgA)

Related topics:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134

Comment: The behavior there seems to be really strange. Forwarding of generic type parameters can work ... but only in very specific cases. https://tsplay.dev/WKO5oW